# Get subsites in Sharepoint ECMAScript

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm trying to use ECMA script in Sharepoint to data on sites.
It's working well for the top root site when I'm using the SP.ClientContext.get_current() method, but I can't seem to get the subsites of this site.
Does anyone know what method I should use to achive that?

Thanks in advance
Avi

Answer (score 5):

Use `get_webs()` function:

```
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
this.webs = clientContext.get_web().get_webs();
```

There is a similar question on [sharepoint.stackexchange.com](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/18776/fetch-list-of-sites-in-site-collection-into-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the name of your site directly in the `SP.ClientContext`:

```
var siteUrl = "/SomeSubsite";
var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
```

Then to get a list, for example, you don't get the current web, but say simply to `get_web()`:

```
var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('SomeList');
```

**Reference:**   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185007(v%3Doffice.14)